# Form data is always empty when using Golang and Bootstrap

Tags: go

So I am trying to use bootstrap to create a form and parse it in golang but the form data keeps coming back empty.

Golang:

```
   // CreateEmployee - handler function for creating a new employee
func CreateEmployee(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(r.Form)
}
```

Bootstrap form:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/employee" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter title">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Photo</label>
            <input type="text" id="photo" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter photo 
             location">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Phonetic</label>
            <input type="text" id="phonetic" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter 
              phonetic pronunciation">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
</body>
```

I am aware that you have to call ParseForm before r.Form is populated but as far as I can tell that is all that is required.

The route is working fine because when I submit the form it is printing an empty map to the console. It seems that I am doing something stupid but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  [name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefname) attribute is missing from the `<input>` elements. If the name attribute is not set or empty, then the input value is not included in the submitted form.

Fix like so:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name">
    </div>
```

... and so on for the other input elements.

Comment: Duh. You are awesome. I knew it was something stupid like that. I have been staring at code too much today and knew I was just overlooking something simple.

Comment: A tip on debugging this: Open your developer console in your browser and click "Network", tick the "Preserve Log" checkbox, then submit your form. You should be able to see the HTTP request, and see if the parameters are there or not. This will help you determine if the problem is on the client (parameters missing) or on the server (parameters look as expected).

Comment: This answer is still a savior in 2021. wasted my 2 hours debugging the entire backend code and finally landed on this answer. Thank you so much.